# Remove the spinner/loading image for error in autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete

Could you please help me on how to remove the spinner/loading image if the autocomplete goes for the error/failure cases?

If i get the error "Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data" i see the loading images and i want to remove that images.

Below is the snippet

```
  $("Autotxt").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Webservice.asmx/GetNames",
            data: "{'prefixText':'" + request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {

                    return {
                        label: item.split('|')[0],
                        val: item.split('|')[1]
                    }
                }))
            },

            error: function (result) {

                alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
                ServiceFailed(result);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");

            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        txtSoID(ui.item.val);
    },
    minLength: 4
});


function txtID(val)
{
alert(val)
}
```

Comment: What is the html of your image?

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the loading class available through the ui, you should be able to do the following:

```
 error: function (result) {
     $('.ui-autocomplete-loading').removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
     // or .hide()
     alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
     ServiceFailed(result);
 },
```

I found the class information on the [jqueryUI development site](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137709/Autocomplete) at the bottom of the page where they talk about css and themes.

Answer (score 2):

I dont see any loading screen in your code. But you could simply add the function

```
var removeSpinner = function() {
    $("yourloader").hide();
}
```

and call it in your failure or error callback like

```
   error: function (result) {
        removeSpinner();
        alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
        ServiceFailed(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an inspect element on those images, check their class ('loader' for example) and then do put this in your error and failure callback `$(".loader").hide()`.

Comment: That would delete the dom node and prevent it from getting called again.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from my answer here, add the following code to execute after a search is complete (even with 0 results):

```
var __response = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response;
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response = function(content) {
    __response.apply(this, [content]);
    this.element.trigger("autocompletesearchcomplete", [content]);
};
```

That code will trigger an event (autocompletesearchcomplete) that you can then bind to:

```
$("#q").bind("autocompletesearchcomplete", function(event, contents) {
    /* Remove spinner here */
});
```

Hope this help...